# Find $a$ and $b$ natural numbers such that $f(1,m)=a+bm$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

Let $f$ be an application defined from $N^2\mapsto N$ with the propriety :

$\begin{cases}
f(0,m) = 1+m  & \text{$\forall m \in N$} \\
f(1+n,0) = f(n,0), & \text{$\forall n \in N$} \\
f(n+1,m+1)=f(n,f(n+1,m)) & \text{$\forall m \in N$, $\forall n \in N$}
\end{cases}$

Find $a$ and $b$ natural numbers such that : $f(1,m) = a+bm$

What i tried :

For $n=0$ we have $f(1,0)=f(0,0)=1+0=1$

and

$f(1,m+1)=f(0,f(1,m))$

we have $f(1,m) \in N$ so $f(0,f(1,m)) = 1 + f(1,m)$ thus $f(1,m+1)= 1 + f(1,m)$

but i can't seem to be able to find a way to continue from here? so i think i might be doing something wrong from the start,i'd like to get some guidance and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(1,m+1)=1+f(1,m)$ then $f(1,m)=1+f(1,m-1)$. Hence $f(1,m+1)=2+f(1,m-1)$. If we continue this way, we obtain $f(1,m+1)=1+m+f(1,0)=m+2$. Thus $f(1,m)=1+m$. Take $a=b=1$.